# Solving trigonometric equation $\sin(x) + \tan(x) =0$

Tags: trigonometry

How you get X when:
$\sin(x) + \tan(x) =0$
It's pretty basic but I just don't understand
What I did until now is:
$\tan(x) = -\sin(x) \Rightarrow \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = -\sin(x)$

But after that I just don't know how to get to an end. 
Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Either you have $\sin x = 0$ or you can simplify the above expression to
$$ - \cos x = 1 $$

Answer (score 0):

If $\sin x=0\Rightarrow x=2k\pi \ (k\in\mathbb{Z})$. Else, after eliminating $\sin x$ both side, it implies $\cos x=-1\rightarrow x=(2k+1)\pi \ (k\in\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: i have just added. my silly mistake. thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

If $$\tan x + \sin x=0$$
then
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin x}{\cos x} + \sin x &= 0 \\
\iff \sin x + \sin x \cos x &=0 \\
\iff \sin x(1+\cos x) &=0
\end{align}
Can you finish from here?